# How to get rid of the blogspot arrow → when you edit a post / page?

Tags: html, blogger, blogs

since the new blogger / blogspot update i've been seeing this useless arrow → when ever i try to edit a post / page , i don't even know what's it used for , but it's so annoying lately since my blogger template does read the image in each page and make it as post thumb - means i have to put an image on the beggining of each page , but when  try edit again this arrow comes on top of the img and the post will not process the img & won't have a thumb. so i have to delete it everytime i finish editing , is there a better way ?

[image: blogger/blogspot (new*) annoying arrow problem]

[image: Mr annoying arrow]

Comment: Maybe it's because of some extention you are using

Comment: no i tried on new page , with the default theme , the same thing happens